# Query next smaller and next bigger instance of model in one queryset in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

For example I have a following model:

```
class Example(models.model):
    number = PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

I have 10 model instances saved in DB  with `number` field like:

[1, 2, 5, 8,  4, 75, 11, 6, 55, 18]

And I would like to query 2 model instances with next smaller and next bigger `number` field to my exact instance.

Example. If I have an instance with `number` 11, than next lower one would be 8 and greater would be 18.

Is it possible to query these 2 closest instances by using Django ORM in one queryset?

Comment: There are no duplicates in the values?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem. No -each one is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain these with:

```
qs1 = Example.objects.filter(
    number__gt=my_number
).order_by('number')[:1]
qs2 = Example.objects.filter(
    number__lt=my_number
).order_by('-number')[:1]

qs = qs1 | qs2
```

Since querysets are lazy, `qs1` and `qs2` will not be evaluated if you do not "consume" these. So if you work with `qs`, then this queryset will contain two, one or no elements (depending on whether there is a next and previous). If there is a next and previous, then both will be in the queryset `qs`.

This will make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT example.*
FROM example
WHERE example.id IN (
       SELECT U0.id FROM example U0
       WHERE U0.number > my_number
       ORDER BY U0.number ASC
       LIMIT 1
   )
   OR example.id IN (
       SELECT U0.id
       FROM example U0
       WHERE U0.number < my_number
       ORDER BY U0.number DESC
       LIMIT 1
   )
```

we can also use `.union` instead:

```
qs1 = Example.objects.filter(
    number__gt=my_number
).order_by('number')[:1]
qs2 = Example.objects.filter(
    number__lt=my_number
).order_by('-number')[:1]

qs = qs1.union(qs2)
```

Then the query looks like:

```
(
    SELECT example.*
    FROM example
    WHERE example.number > 5
    ORDER BY example.number ASC
    LIMIT 1
) UNION (
    SELECT example.*
    FROM example
    WHERE example.number < 5
    ORDER BY example.number DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works only with union.